# rentention of prometheus data for a specific period of time

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am looking at saving the prometheus data of last year between sept-nov. I do not want to save the prometheus data of the remaining year except to have the latest 3 months of data.
So that I will have last three months latest data and also can compare the data between sept-nov of last year to the present year.

I need help in understanding how I can achieve this requirement, so that I can reduce the cost and also to have my comparison with last year data for a specific time frame and not to maintain the data of the entire year which will be a overhead and extra cost.

Thanks in advance(my systems are on eks)

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Prometheus. You can set retention policy, to store uninterrupted periods of data. Additionally you can remove individual metrics, but AFAIK only for all time of that metric existence. Maybe some long time storage solutions (like Mimir or Thanos) might help you, but I'm not sure if any of them has desired functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Prometheus service used for monitoring the cluster runs and stores its data on the management node. By default, Prometheus metrics are stored for seven days and you can change this period in the Prometheus configuration file by doing the following:

On the management node, open the /etc/sysconfig/prometheus file to   edit, set the needed retention period for the STORAGE_RETENTION    option, and then save your changes. For example:

```
STORAGE_RETENTION="--storage.tsdb.retention.time=90d"
```

Restart the Prometheus service:

```
systemctl restart prometheus.service
```

**Note** -In Prometheus it is not possible to set a retention period for a specific year directly or for certain months. The retention period in Prometheus is based on duration or interval specified rather than being dedicated to specific year.

The retention period in Prometheus is defined in terms of duration, typically specified in **hours, days, weeks or months**.

Comment: this will let me store only the data for for last 90 days, what abt the 90 days data of last year? i need to make sure to have my data from sept-nov of year 2022. by the year 2023, i should be in a position to compare my 2023 sept data to that of last year. During this period, i do not want to store my data of the remaining months to reduce storage cost and improve performance